# Large inventory list in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I need to create an inventory list with about 2 million items in SharePoint.

The list is populated from a one time import (backend) and then with daily updates of about 1000 items every night (also backend). The list will have a lot of columns (about 30-40)

From the users perspective, the list will be a read only list used for lookup only. The user needs to be able to look up a single item by Inventory id, or a group of items (let's say up to 100 items) by a category. They also need to search for items based on a text string matching a single line text column.

What I need to know is if I will run into trouble because of the list view threshold or other limitations. The user should never see more than a certain number of items, usually a single item or a group of 10-20 items. We could even set a max limit for a filter or search operation if that helps us avoid running into LVT issues.

Still, the total number of items is quite large, and I have heard others have run into issues concerning global operations on the list (e.g. permissions). Also I have heard that crawling might take a long time with this many items.

- Will I be able to make this work in SharePoint with this many items?
- Do I need to look at e.g. content Query web parts or metadata
  navigation to support this scenario?
- Is SharePoint the right choice
  for this at all?

Input is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would use folders if you are seriously considering to store that many items in the list. Try to have no more that 3000-5000 items in each folder for instance. Also, It would be wise to first populate your list with test data and see how it behaves in terms of performance. And you could also think about storing the data in the SQL table and create an external list that work with it. This way you are much less likely hit performance problems. 2 millions items with 30-40 columns in a SharePoint list might be very hard to optimize and requires a lot of testing and thinking.

Comment: Thanks for Your comments, Denis. Using folders seems difficult for me, 2M items in folders of max 5000 items would result in 400+ folders. I would not know how to manage all the folders. Populating With test data is an excellent suggestion, that I will definately try out. I have also been thinking of external lists, but does that require Enterprise License? (using BDC I assume?)

Comment: Yes, it does require enterprise licenses.